# Hosting Web application into Local IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to access Directory path in Local IIS server

I had Implemented Web application in asp.net mvc there i had created 2 hyperlinks and i had writen code for when click the hyper link .exe file will open.it working when run the application but when i hosted application into local IIS server there when i click hyperlink in browser i am not getting any thing.

```
    public ActionResult MQReaderSetupPage()
    {


        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
       process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\setup.exe";            
        process.Start();
       return View(process);
    }
```

Comment: Your code will start the .exe process on the server. There is no way to return the .exe process to the user's browser.

Comment: yes your correct but when i hosted the application into local IIS server . exe was not started and i had seen in event viewer log there is a message "could not connect to server".

Comment: I'm not sure about `UseShellExecute = false`. Try `UseShellExecute = true` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It is hard to know, because you have not supplied the code for `setup.exe` or provided a description about what it is supposed to do?